# Failed to migrate Azure VM to managed disks

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage

Trying to transition from unmanaged to managed disks to save costs. Currently, I'm using this VM to develop AS, IS and RS in Visual Studio – MacOS user here. Today I detected an unusual billing pattern corresponding to my 'storage' so I decided to shift to managed disks but I'm receiving this error:

```
Failed to migrate the virtual machine 'XX-Personal-DEV'. Error: Operation 'convertToManagedDisks' is not allowed on VM 'JD-Personal-DEV' since VM has extension 'SqlIaasExtension' in failed state.
```

I googled it but I can't find anything related to this error. How can I solve it?

Comment: Could [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ujpat/2017/01/19/automated-backups-configuration-fails-when-configured-from-azure-portal/) article help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, you should delete the failed extenstion and try again.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes